# How to Select DuckDuckGo Element. AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, search, duckduckgo-api

I'm trying to use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to gather search results from [DuckDuckGo's Search API](https://duckduckgo.com/api).

Here's the JavaScript I've written so far:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.duckduckgo.com/',
  data: { q: myhomestate, format: 'json', pretty: 1 },
  jsonpCallback: 'jsonp',
  listLocation: "RelatedTopics",
  dataType: 'text'
}).then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
}
```

The code works fine, but it just returns a big JSON object, and I don't know how to select any of its elements. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`data = JSON.parse(data);`**

turns it into a normal JavaScript object. Then you can select elements like you would any other object.

---

*e.g.*

`var heading = data.Heading;`

`var developer = data.meta.developer[0].name`

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert JSON response into JSON Object, as shown below :

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);
```

Then you can access, it's fields as shown below :

```
console.log(jsonObj["RelatedTopics"]);
```